# I don't want to lose photo on image view button when come back from other app

Tags: android, uiimageview, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

Users can show their photo on the imageView button. Codes are given below.

The problem is, **savedInstanceState** returns **null** since photo on the imageView is obtained in the **onActivityResult** function.

Therefore, if users click on **btnRegistration** and ***come back*** to this app again, they ***lose photo on the imageView***. 
Could you please help, how to edit these codes to solve this problem

```
private var iv_crop: ImageView = null
public var tmpResultUri: Uri?=null

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            val cimg = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
            iv_crop.setImageURI(cimg.uri)
            val resultUri = cimg.uri
             tmpResultUri = resultUri 
 }}

 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {  
                var strResultUri: String?= null
                strResultUri = savedInstanceState.getString(strResultUri)  

               // var drawable: BitmapDrawable = iv_crop.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable
               //var bitmapImgCropped = drawable.getBitmap()
        }
        else {
            iv_crop.setOnClickListener {
                CropImage.activity().start(this)  // <== Starts a new activity here. 
            }                          

        }

       btnRegistration?.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.setClassName( "com.mylab.myApp","com.mylab.myApp.MainActivity")
                startActivity(intent)   // <== Starts a new activity here.
                finish()}
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState:Bundle ) {
        outState.run{
            outState.putString(tmpResultUri.toString(), tmpResultUri.toString())
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState!!)    
        savedInstanceState.run {
            val strtmpResultUri = getString(tmpResultUri.toString())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your image URI using a static key. Something like this.

```
companion object { 
    private const val ARG_IMAGE_URI = "imageuri"
}
```

Then when you save and retrieve your URI, use this value as your key and not the uri.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState:Bundle ) {
    outState.putString(ARG_IMAGE_URI, tmpResultUri.toString())
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


   if (savedInstanceState != null) {  
       val strResultUri: String?= savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_IMAGE_URI)
   }

}
```

Comment: Where should I define this companion object? Also, the problem is onSaveInstanceState is called before getting image uri, which was obtained in the onActivityResult. (I am try to say that onActivityResult is called before leaving the current activity, before getting image uri).   After coming CropImage activity, onSaveInstanceState is null